# Default Mac OS X Apache server stopped working after MAMP installation (checked ports)

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

I have installed MAMP server recently. Now when I'm trying to start default Mac OS X Apache server it's not working. I've checked the ports: default server uses 80 port, and MAMP uses 8888 port. When I run `sudo apachectl start` command in Terminal it says that operation is already in progress. What happened with my default server?

Thank you.

Comment: have you checked your config using `apachectl configtest`?

Comment: @John `httpd: Syntax error on line 547 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /Applications/Cache/csp/bin/CSPa22.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/Cache/csp/bin/CSPa22.so, 10): Symbol not found: _ap_log_error\n  Referenced from: /Applications/Cache/csp/bin/CSPa22.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /Applications/Cache/csp/bin/CSPa22.so`

Comment: comment the line out and try again..

Comment: @John I've commented the loading of this module. It appears this is Content-Security-Policy module and now I'm getting Error 403.

Comment: try `ps -ef | grep apache` and if there's a process running, try to kill it.. afterwards, try to start apache as usual..

Comment: @John Server works. I can go to localhost:80 but localhost/~mityakoval is Forbidden

Comment: well this is probably a different problem and maybe related to file/folder permissions..